# Можно ли использовать табы в табах?

Tags: android, tabs

У меня есть программа с 3 табами, созданными с помощью TabLayout & ViewPager с горизонтальной прокруткой. Каждый таб это определённая часть программы, но в одном табе н помещается все, что я хотел разместить, поэтому я хотел бы разместить в каждом табе по 2 таба с вертикальной прокруткой. Первый таб основной функционал, а если свайпом достать снизу второй таб, там дополнительный вариант. Если в первом случае 3 таба это фрагменты, которые находятся в активити, то вертикальные табы (тоже фрагменты) будут располагаться одном из 3х табов, то есть в фрагменте.
Можно ли так делать и какие интервенты нужно использовать для вертикальных табов? Достаточно ли будет одного ViewPager? И может есть более правильный вариант реализации моей затеи.

Сначала думал сделать выдвижную боковую панель и там сделать 3 пункта. По переходу на каждый пункт пользователь бы попадал в активность с двумя горизонтальными табами. Но захотел сделать как описал выше.

Comment: В гайдлайнах советуется не смешивать разные элементы интерфейса, а выбрать что-то одно. Табы не могут не помещаться. Когда места на экране не хватает, появляется горизонтальный скроллинг

Comment: скроллинг мне не подходит. Тут даже не то что не посещается, а разделение функционала. Программа делится на 3 основные части и каждая часть на 2

Answer (score 1):

Viber хороший промер выхода из ситуации. У них тоже есть табы в табах, но сделали они умнее, т.е. верхний уровень табов скролится, а вложенный нет, переключение вложеных табов реализовано по средством нажатия на них, тем более просто представьте на секунду свою идею, как бы это выглядело и смогло ли бы вообще работать? Просто сами подумайте, когда табы в табах и оба могу скролится, то какой должен таб должен проскролится, когда вы пальцем проведёте? Системе нужно будет прочитать ваши мысли и т.п.? Как система поймёт, что именно вы хотите проскролить? В общем лажа получится.

Comment: А разве система не различает горизонтальные и вертикальные жесты? Если свайпнул горизонтально, то скролятся горизонтальные табы, а если свайпнул вертикально, то тогда другие табы.

Comment: @GregoryBass Я точно не помню, но если вы добавите в свой таб ListView, который скролится вертикально, то всё будет работать нормально. Что до горизонтальных табов, то такого я точно не слыхал, попробуйте ListView или RecyclerView

Comment: Как раз RecyclerView планируется разместиться в нижних табах)) я думал что табы в табах можно переключать кнопками. Можно сделать это как 2 активити, только я хотел чтобы этого не было заметно. А просто взял и "достал" снизу второй экран с дополнительными возможностями